# Show text for each listview items

Tags: java, android

Can someone help me with this very simple question. I'm very+++ beginner.

This is my string for `listview`

```
String[] items = {"Silent night", "Deck The hall","Feliz navidad","Jingle bell", "song 4","song 5"};
```

Question:

How do I view lyric for each item in my listview? I store my lyric in res raw.

Details:

I have main `textview` and 4 buttons (Christmas, hillsong, button 3,button 4) in main.xml. When I click the Christmas button, it switches to the Christmas layout with Christmas songs list in the `listview`.  When the title is clicked it refers back to main.xml and view the lyric in main `textview`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html for some good examples on using listviews

Basically you'll create a new class that extends ListActivity.

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        String[] values = new String[] { "song1", "song2", "song3",
                "song4" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Then you'll need to check when the user clicks a list item and then pack it in and send it through an intent to your next activity with is lyrics.

```
@Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Lyrics.class);
                    intent.putExtra("song", item); //item is the listitem ie. song1, etc.
                    startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Finally in the lyrics class you'll need to retrieve the extras.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null) {
        String song = extras.getString("song");
        }
...
}
```

Now you have the song in the lyrics activity and you can take it from there. I pretty much just wrote your entire app.... x_X